# Why was there no hint of the Joker?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises

In Dark Knight Rises, we see a bit of history of what has happened to Gotham in the past 8 years.

Batman in seclusion, criminals being locked up for being part of organized crime, and Gordon's guilt from what happened with Dent.

However, there seems to be **absolutely no mention** of the Joker at all during the movie, not even a *hint* at what happened to him after being apprehended.  In comparison, Crane has been seen across all three movies and given some sort of wrap-up.

Granted, it is a *tad* hard to film anything new with the death of the actor.

But is there any reason Nolan gave on why he wouldn't at least give us a visual *hint* at the Joker being locked up (example being a pan across a door reading **EXTREMELY DANGEROUS**) or him escaping into hiding (example: Gordon saying to a fellow officer that "*The Madman still got away*")?

Comment: i read on a Nolan interview that they might use some old dark knight movie footage in Dark knight rises with Joker on it. Not sure if we will see it in the directors cut or something.

Comment: @Morpheus I had heard similar rumours but Nolan squashed them closer to release.  It would be nice if they did include them as a bit of a tribute when the release the inevitable Trilogy collectors pack.

Comment: This page was an interesting read http://screenrant.com/batman-3-dark-knight-rises-joker-heath-ledger-kofi-89946/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per this [link](http://www.hollywood.com/news/Christopher_Nolan_not_referencing_Ledgers_Jokers_fate_in_new_Batman_film/29030407):

> Director Christopher Nolan decided against referencing Heath Ledger's The Joker character in the new Batman film, insisting acknowledging the "real-life tragedy" of the late star was "inappropriate"....
>   He explains, "We're not addressing The Joker at all. That is something I felt very strongly about in terms of my relationship with Heath and the experience I went through with him on The Dark Knight. I didn't want to in any way try and account for a real-life tragedy. That seemed inappropriate to me. We just have a new set of characters and a continuation of Bruce Wayne's story, not involving The Joker."

Answer (score 12):

I think the only reason I could think of presently is the fact that Nolan wanted to preserve the memory of the character created by Heath Ledger and decided to end it with Dark Knight. Any reference to him in the movie would've created a scene portraying him since he isn't alive the creators would've refrained from making any reference to it which could've resulted in negative publicity / reception because of his iconic portrayal in Dark Knight.

Given the Fact "Spoilers below"

We see Liam Neeson's character speaking to Bruce again even though he was killed off in the First movie, had Heath Ledger been alive I think we could've seen a different take on the whole movie with Joker probably playing another major role (Because of Heath Ledger's dialogue in Dark knight ***"I think you and I are destined to this forever"***)

As for what could've happened to Dark knight. The last scene where he is shown is the scene where is hanging on the building towards the end of Dark knight where the swat team enters pointing their gun at him.

My assumption is that they could've taken him to Arkham because of his instability as the reason, where he could've been mourning over the failure of his plan and also since there was no activity about Batman finding no inspiration he could've died at Arkham or broken free and leave the city for good. or He could've been killed by the SWAT team because he killed many cops, blew up hospitals. I don't think he was put along with Dent's prisoners because if that was the case he would've been brought back out during the war sequences towards the end, so I think he died at some point during the peaceful times in Gotham and if he had left Gotham definitely the war at Gotham would've prompted him to come back to join in on the fun.

Comment: I have a inkling that Crane's role in DKR was intended for Joker

Comment: very well could be. I think two face would've made a tremendous judge. ;)

Comment: @TylerShads I don't think this *Roland Freisler*-role would have fit to the *Joker*, since he would be too crazy and uncontrollable for that, I think. He doesn't want any rich or government people punished, he just wants everybody to go mad. If he were there during the occupation he would have rather been up to his own things than support *Bane*.

Comment: @ChristianRau True point.  Counter-argument is that he would think it would be good fun to make people go mad with the choice, knowing what they face.  The line "Death......by Exile" seems like something that would be said by the Joker.  That and the whole occupation seems to go hand in hand with something he said to Dent "Upset the established order and everything becomes *chaos*"

Comment: This provided a very interesting read http://www.themarysue.com/joker-dark-knight-rises/